# Gate drive transformer troubleshoot

Tags: transistors, high-frequency

Recently I've been working on a half-bridge solid state tesla coil project.
After doing some research, I came across a lot of universal tesla coil driver schematics, and I've realised that a lot of the schematics use a gate drive transformer instead of a traditional driver ic.
From my understanding, a gate drive transformer has better galvanic isolation and eliminates the need for a bootstrap IC. So I've decided to try out this method of driving the gate.

[image]

This is what I come up with. The toroid for the gate driver transformer is taken from a boost converter board. It works at 500khz, so I hope this ferrite core has higher permeability.
The working frequency is 170kHz.
The supply voltage for the tc4420 is 12v, the capacitor is a poly film capacitor 1uf and the resistor is a 5ohm 2-watt resistor.

The problem is when I used a multimeter to check the output voltage on the secondary the multimeter shows very little voltage reading (mv) and the 5ohm resistor gets bloody hot, and after removing the capacitor and the resistor directly hooking the transformer to the driver ic there is around 9v on the secondary side.
I know that a multimeter is not a suitable instrument used to measure the value but currently I don't own an oscilloscope.

Hopefully, I can overcome this problem or I might just stick with the traditional driver ic method.

Thank you.

Comment: build a bridge rectifier from fast diodes (eg: 1N4148) and use that to rectify the AC output from the transformer. measure this DC.

Comment: Thank you @jasen i will try it out

Comment: Great im getting 11v on the secondary when measured the rectified ac,now thats been solved another problem also exist the 5ohm resistor get pretty hot and the tc4420 also gets little bit hot but the resistor is just steaming.i measured the circuits current consumption it around 200ma

Comment: @Mr.Infinite The TC4420 is a *flurgen* mosfet driver, not a transformer driver. It's peak output current is there to charge and discharge a capacitive gate for a *short time*, not drive a *flurgen* inductive transformer primary! Where did you find someone recommending this specific circuit? It's wonderful you are getting results. And I don't want to rain on your parade. But I'm not entirely happy, either.

Comment: @jonk its not like an actual transformer outputting power.its a pulse transformer to drive the gate of the mosfets even the datasheet states that the tc4420 is suitable to drive pulse transformer

Comment: @Mr.Infinite But it is driving an inductor and not a capacitor. These are quite dissimilar things. (I just want you to think a little about what's going on and why it is going on. I haven't considered the details, myself. But I smell problems with so simplistic an approach.)

Comment: @jonk yes technically the tc4420 is a capacitive load driver,but i wanted to have a galvanic isolation between the power mosfets and my drive circuitary.perhaps can you give any other solution.there are people succesfully used this method but ya i know there are advantages and disadvantages to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hot resistor means high RMS current .Your driver transformer could be driven into saturation .Remember the Volt microsecond rating of the transformer .170 KHz drives it about 3 times as hard as 500KHz .Nore turns will help ,so would a larger core or a pulse transformer with a better volt mircosecond rating .

Comment: did you meant more turns?ive replaced the resistor with 1.5ohm now the resistor doesnt get hot anymore and the driver ic is slightly warm but im still looking for ways to improve the overall efficiency.so i will increase the number of turns and update you-thank you

Comment: Thank you very much  @Autistic ive increased the number of turns now the circuit works flawlessly not even getting warm and the frequancy,amplitude and duty cycle is perfectly same as the input.thank you very much